# Own Cloud PHP-Modul cURL

Tags: php, curl, nginx, owncloud

I try to install own cloud on my raspberry pi. 
When I call the url, it shows me this:

[image]

I use nginx and php-fpm and I have no idea, whats wrong..
phpinfo(); works perfect!

I hope, you can help me!

Thank you, and have a nice day ;)

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [my ip];
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # enforce https
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name [my ip];

    ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/cloudssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/cloudssl.key;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www/cloud;

    client_max_body_size 10G;
    # set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

    index index.html index.php;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
            deny all;
    }

    location / {
            # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
            rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
            rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

            rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
            rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

            rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
            try_files $1 = 404;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what you don't understand. `PHP module cURL not installed` is pretty clear. You need to install the php module cURL (I'm not sure anymore, but I think it's `php5-curl` if you want to install it via `apt-get`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5

Comment: im so dump... -.-
this moment, when you overlook the obvious... xD
just apt-get install php5-curl :D

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is about 2 years old but I had nearly the same problem with php7.2 now. I updated my server from Ubuntus LTS Version 16 to 18.
My problem was the same as yours, I installed everything from php7.2 (included fpm and curl) but I got the same message when I tried to use the web client:

> PHP-Modul cURL nicht installiert. Bitte kontaktieren Sie Ihren Server-Administrator und bitten Sie um die Installation des Moduls. PHP-Module wurden installiert, werden aber als noch fehlend gelistet? Bitte kontaktieren Sie Ihren Server-Administrator und bitten Sie um den Neustart des Webservers.

I solved this problem in my nginx configuration! There I had the entry:

```
upstream mycloud {
  server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

changed this to:

```
upstream mycloud {
  server unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

and of course the fastcgi entry too:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

Struggled for a while now with this but now it works like a charm :) I hope this will help someone in the future with a nginx php-fpm server ;)